# Change position of Google title on the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to make a button at the left bottom corner, but here is Google title. Can i will move this? Or have i right to nothing to do? I mean about copyrighting, cause my button cover the Google logo.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWPqp.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can change Google Logo, Default Maps Control by providing padding:

```
googleMap.setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

Here's more information about changing padding from the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding